# Does JVM/.net framework include "linker and loader"?

Tags: .net, linux, linker, jvm, loader

We know that for c/cpp compilation, there'll be linking and loading phase, which requires system level linker and loader.

My question: Java and .net have JVM/.net framework as execution sand box, while both sand box has the ability to "JIT" pcode like file into native code.

I wonder if both "JIT" mechanism will have to involve anything like linker and loader ino-rder to make code runnable at local environment. If yes, do they use standard OS linker/loader, or JVM/.net framework implement their own?

Thanks!

Comment: The JVM loads classes and links them together in a Java specific way, the OS doesn't get involved.

Comment: The linker is a component of the compiler toolchain, not of the OS.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, the dynamic linker (e.g. `ld-linux.so`) is part of the OS since it's not shipped with the executables themselves but a dependency.